# Excel save as box

Tags: vba, excel, filedialog

I'm hoping you guys can help me. I don't really know a lot about vb coding, only some extreme basics.

I'm trying to get my destfile to = Application.FileDialog, but I'm not quite sure how to go about it.
I know how to make a default path destination to my current code, but I'd rather have a browse to save as box.
Any help by chance?

Here is my current code.

```
Sub QuoteCommaExport()
   ' Dimension all variables.
   Dim DestFile As String
   Dim FileNum As Integer
   Dim ColumnCount As Integer
   Dim RowCount As Integer
   ' Prompt user for destination file name.
   DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
      & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Quote-Comma Exporter")
   ' Obtain next free file handle number.
   FileNum = FreeFile()
   ' Turn error checking off.
   On Error Resume Next
   ' Attempt to open destination file for output.
   Open DestFile For Output As #FileNum
   ' If an error occurs report it and end.
   If Err <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Cannot open filename " & DestFile
      End
   End If
   ' Turn error checking on.
   On Error GoTo 0
   ' Loop for each row in selection.
   For RowCount = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
      ' Loop for each column in selection.
      For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count

         ' Write current cell's text to file with quotation marks.
         Print #FileNum, StrConv("""" & Selection.Cells(RowCount, _
            ColumnCount).Text & """", 1);
         ' Check if cell is in last column.
         If ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count Then
            ' If so, then write a blank line.
            Print #FileNum,
         Else
            ' Otherwise, write a comma.
            Print #FileNum, ",";
         End If
      ' Start next iteration of ColumnCount loop.
      Next ColumnCount
   ' Start next iteration of RowCount loop.
   Next RowCount
   ' Close destination file.
   Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add 4 blanks before code, this way it looks nice. (I tried editing your question but made a mistake somewhere).

Comment: Yeah, I posted using bbcode originally, then was figuring it out. thanks.

Comment: This is old VB code, not Excel VBA (at least it hasn't been for a decade or so). Perhaps a search here for `[vba] FileDialog` would give you examples of using it, and then you could update it to actually use Excel's built-in SaveAs support for CSV files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library.

Then you will have the ability to create an Application.FileDialog box.

Code for a fileDialog looks something like:

```
Dim fDialog
Dim fLocation
Dim varFile as variant
        Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        With fDialog
            .Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xlsx, *.xlsb, *.xlsm, *.xls", 1
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Title = "Please select the file you want to use"
            If .Show = True Then
                ImportCK = MsgBox("Are you you want to use this file?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Saving...")
                If ImportCK = vbYes Then
                    For Each varfile In .SelectedItems
                        fLocation = varfile
                    Next
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "You clicked Cancel.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Canceled"
                 'Do something on cancel
            End If
        End With
```

The above code allows a user to pick a file and returns the address of the file.

If you want the user to only select a folder the code is similiar but a few lines are changed.

```
Dim fDialog
Dim fLocation
Dim varFile as variant
        'Create a folder picker
        Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        With fDialog
            .Title = "Please select the folder you want to use"
            If .Show = True Then
                ImportCK = MsgBox("Are you you want to use this folder?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Saving...")
                If ImportCK = vbYes Then
                    For Each varfile In .SelectedItems
                        fLocation = varfile
                    Next
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "You clicked Cancel.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Canceled"
                 'Do something on cancel
            End If
        End With
```

This is for VBA in an Excel Macro.

Comment: Yeah, I already knew that specific command, but thank you for the help.
I'm trying to get a save as command working in the same context of that box.
Essentially the same type of view you see, when you go to file > save as. not File > open.
Not sure if the application.filedialog is even the correct command to run what I want. Hence asking you guys.

Comment: Nevermind, looked up application syntax, and found the correct command I need. msoFileDialogSaveAs. thanks for the help though guys!